# Creating a Macro in VBA out of four Excel formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on ways to improve an Excel file that is updated throughout the day on an hourly basis. Currently I have the worksheet set up with four index Match formulas to auto populate some of the data that is entered every time one specific value is entered in column 2(B).

Recently my team has had to share this data with another team by giving them permissions to the file. This team is not a reporting team so they have this bad habit of editing cells with formulas and making things not work properly.

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out with trying to come up with a MACRO that could integrate these formulas in the same order so that the formulas need not be directly on the workbook and possibly edited over.

I am newer To macros and have not built one like this as of yet.

The formulas are set as the following with the name of the sheet being matched to Sheet2:

```
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(C394,2)="19",INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!D:D,0),1),IF(LEFT(C394,1)="3",INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!H:H,0),1),INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!J:J,0),1))),"")
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(C394,2)="19",INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!D:D,0),3),IF(LEFT(C394,1)="3",INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!H:H,0),3),INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!J:J,0),3))),"") 
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(C394,2)="19",INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!D:D,0),5),IF(LEFT(C394,1)="3",INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!H:H,0),5),INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!J:J,0),5))),"")
=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(C394,2)="19",INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!D:D,0),6),IF(LEFT(C394,1)="3",INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!H:H,0),6),INDEX(Sheet2!A:T,MATCH(C394,Sheet2!J:J,0),6))),"")
```

The result looks like something similar to this:

```
9999999  Department 1   SMITH,ROBERT    JANE DOE    JOHN DOE
```

9999999  Is the value we enter manually the other four values are populated by the formula.

Comment: soooooooo what have you tried? Luckily for you this is easy :D

Comment: Well so far from what I have been able to find I can only see "switch" or "choose" functions for macros, but these are not exaclty what I am seeking since it would require I put all 300+ possible entries for that first field into the list so select from. So far the actual formulas are working that I had set in place..I am just wishing to replace them if possible with a macro since they seem to run without slowing down the processes on the sheet itself

Answer (score 0):

Write all formulas at once with a one-size-fits-all formula.

```
range("d394:g394").formula = _
  "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$F, MATCH($C394, INDEX(Sheet2!$D:$J, 0, 7-(LEFT($C394,2)="19")*6-(LEFT($C394)="3")*2), 0), CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A), 1, 3, 5, 6)),TEXT(,))"
```

You should be able to expand that range to include more rows.